# Adding jquery to html5blank Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

how do I actually add jQuery to html5blank wordpress theme by toddmotto? 
I'm quite new to wordpress so I'm not really sure how does this work.

For normal html, I'll just link a script tag of jquery and another script tag with $(document).ready.. . . . . and start the jquery codes.

Would really love if someone who had experience using html5blank theme could shed some light.

Thanks much!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? As you say, just add a scritptag that liks to jQuery and it's up and running.

Comment: Hi Steven, when I read up they say if I include jQuery in the header.php it might be loaded twice if I install a plugin. So I'm not too sure about how Wordpress works when it comes to jQuery. Is there a proper way of adding jQuery to Wordpress or have you tried adding the jQuery script tags and does it work? Looking forward to your reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I load all my scripts from `functions.php` by using [wp_enqeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). This will avoid duplicate loading.

If you only want to load Query, you can do this by:

```
function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts' );
```

This will load the jQuery that follows WP. You can see other [default scripts you can load here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script):

If you want to load other JS scripts, then you must use this:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

The `array('jquery')` is for dependencies and in this case means that jQuery must be loaded before this script can be loaded.

If you want to register a newer version of jQuery, you first have to deregister the loaded jQuery:

```
 wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
```

Comment: Why are you enqueing the default stylesheet? For the OP purposes, jQuery should be added as dependency in your example, no?

Comment: Sorry, I just copied an example from the WP page. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Steven, sorry ok so I have to add the wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); and automatically it will include the jquery library? Or do I have to download jQuery library and saved it in a folder and declare it somewhere?

Comment: No, Wordpress comes with a bunch of libraries, including jquery. So it's enough to just use `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`. If this helps you, then please upvote my answer and mark it s solved :)

Answer (score 2):

The WordPress recommends add jquery from WordPress itself.So you can add jquery using following way.

**Add code to your current theme functions.php file.**

```
function func_add_my_jquery() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'func_add_my_jquery' );
```